# Special property of multiples of 6

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can it be proved that if $n$ is a multiple of $6$, then there exists a subset of the proper divisors of $n$ that add up to $n$?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether all perfect numbers are multiples of $6$? Or that multiples of $6$ are the only numbers with enough proper divisors to even hope to be perfect?

Comment: The question is not clear to me.

Comment: No
I stumbled upon this problem from here
https://www.codechef.com/problems/MCHEF001
In point 2, it is clear that the sum of subsets of factor of that number should not be equal to itself.

Comment: After going through various contestants, I saw one has just checked for multiples of 6 for satisfying point 2 of the question i.e if a number is a multiple of 6 then subset of its proper divisors add up to that number. Same is not with other number.

Comment: eg : Lets say number is 18 = 6*3
so its proper divisors will be {1,2,3,6,9}
also 3+6+9=18

Comment: the edit made the question better. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Are you just asking for $N + 2N + 3N = 6N$?

Comment: I think that the implicit question is this: which numbers are "special numbers" in the sense indicated by the link?  That is, is there a classification of the numbers $n$ for which there does not exist a subset of its proper divisors that sums to $n$?

Comment: It's clear that any multiple of a [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) will not be special, but it's not obvious whether these are the only instances.

Comment: For simplicity, apparently the English name for the numbers that satisfy $(1)\land (2)$ is [*weird number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weird_number). See [OEIS A006037](https://oeis.org/A006037). A number which satisfies $\neg(2)$ is called *semiperfect* (or *pseudoperfect*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $n$ is a multiple of $6$. Then the set of its divisors contains $\frac{n}{2}$, $\frac{n}{3}$, and $\frac{n}{6}$ which sum to $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that if $n$ is a multiple of $6$, then there exists a subset of factors to $n$ that adds up to $n$.  If $n = 6k$, then the subset $\{k,2k,3k\} = \{\frac n6, \frac n3, \frac n2\}$ adds up to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it also follows from definition,  that any multiple of a [semiperfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiperfect_number) works.

It's literally, that $n$ divided by each of divisors of the semiperfect numbers $y$, that sum to $y$, will then sum to $n$.